# Is there a way to track the frequency of a relationship between two columns?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-charts

I have two columns in a spread sheet where column A tracks about 100 different categories. In Column B, I have a formula that maps specific categories in Column A to one of 10 separate categories in Column B.

These are all non-numerical values, and I'd like to track the frequency of Rows of Categories in Column B, with each bar in the graph breaking up into a stacked graph representing the frequency of recurrences of Column A.

Is this possible?

Comment: A copy of your spreadsheet would be helpful.

Comment: @ZygD -- I can't share the actual sheet I'm working on, but made a very crude mock up of the situation: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/14L3qrFURTHKPJPl6v-5tB518WQpti06zdtFL1FYP6tE/edit?usp=sharing

In this sheet ranges 1-3 will always be a value of A in column B, 4-6 B, and 6-9 C. I'm trying to create a graph that displays the count of A B and C, broken up into stacks with a count of each instance of the numeric values in A.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `query()` to pivot the data into as many columns as there are unique categories in column B, like this:

```
=query( 
  A2:B, 
  "select A, count(A) 
   where B is not null 
   group by A 
   pivot B", 
  0 
)
```

Then use the result table to insert a chart that has ten stacked bars.

Comment: Thanks! What's the reference for the A2:B query here? Am I meant to point at an entire column? That doesn't seem to be working for me here.

Comment: Put the formula in cell `D1` in your [sample spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/14L3qrFURTHKPJPl6v-5tB518WQpti06zdtFL1FYP6tE/edit?usp=sharing). It will create a table with the unique values in column `A` as the first column and the counts by values A, B and C in three additional columns.